# Notes & Attachments Data Not Available

Tags: visualforce, permissions, attachment

I am using an outputLink and want to give the user the opportunity to add a Note to a Contact like so:

```
<apex:outputLink title="Add a Note" value="/002/e?parent_id={!contact.Id}&retURL=/{!contact.Id}">
    <span class="newObject addNote"></span>
</apex:outputLink>
```

This generates a URL like this: https://na12.salesforce.com/002/e?parent_id=003U000000PL9LNIA1&retURL=%2F003U000000PL9LNIA1 which gives me the following error:

> Data Not Available The data you were trying to access could not be
>   found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system
>   error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it,
>   please look at our support page.

If I replace the parentId and retURL with an Opportunity, the New Note page is displayed correctly (obviously for the Opportunity, not the Contact).

I therefore thought maybe I didn't have Edit permissions on the Contact I wanted to add the Note to.  Looking at the System Info, however, I am a System Administrator and have Read, Edit, Create, Delete permissions, not to mention View All and Modify All.

I can't see any other permissions that have to do with Notes & Attachments.  How can I associate a Note to the Contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL generated was using IDs with 18 characters.  When I chopped off the last three from each parameter, the page loaded without issue.

Comment: That's odd, both 15 and 18 char should work okay.

Comment: same is happening for me, I'm having to chop the last few characters off to get it to work